# API.AI Intent won't save when adding Required Action

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a chat bot that will help users search up motorcycles.

I'm new to API.AI and have set up my entities and their synonyms, my intent and user expressions, as well as references to the entities (@engineSize, @make, @bikeType).

My problem is when I try to add a required action and prompt, and then try to save the intent, I get the following message: 
"The following entities reference each other and form an infinite loop: [engineSize]."

Initially I thought I was using the references wrong in the user expressions.  I deleted every reference except for one expression which uses all three entities.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!  Pix below for further details.

EDIT:  I fixed one of the issues of trying to pass a template expression as an example.  However, I still get the same error message.  I will replace and update my image links to include the edits.

[Annotated User expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXaAg.png)

[Required Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnl8S.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the answer to this post would have been difficult to find because the problem was in defining my entities.

In the entity definitions, I included an @ref to the entity itself.  ie the bikeType entity contained @bikeType as one of its definitions.

This is not to be mistaken with the User Expressions.  As long as the user expression is marked as a Template (the entire line is denoted with an '@' on the far left, as opposed to a large " ), there should be no issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited for clarity to get at root problem**

In the provided user input examples you give the intent, you are supposed to provide general examples and then highlight any text belonging to an entity to map where entities appear in user's inquiries.

In your case, you have input the actual entity reference '@engineSize' as an example belonging to the engineSize entity, creating a self reference.

A proper provided user example would look like:

[image]

Also note though that if you are just using entities to store generic information like numbers, addresses, times, etc. it generally makes far more sense to use prebuilt system entities for those categories than create a custom entity, for example @sys.number-integer might be exactly what you need

It looks like you need to get a firmer understanding of entities, for which I would recommend the documentation:
https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-entities

Comment: Thanks Matt, I spent quite some time reading through the documentation and fixed my references (or so I believe).

I've also edited the original post to include updated screenshots.  However, I'm still facing the same issue.  To be clear, I scrapped all my expressions and remade all my entities.  Then I added just one expression that references one entity.  When I checked the box to require an action for that entity, I still received the infinite loop error message.

Comment: It looks like you're still doing the same thing now with bikeType. Don't put '@bikeType' in what the user would say. Put an example bike type and highlight it as an example of the bikeType entity.

Comment: It is my understanding that using @bikeType:bikeType is an acceptable format if you specify the expression as a Template and not an Example.  Even if it were not, I have tried your suggestion and only included 1 expression by highlighting the word "cruiser" and I was still stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Per api.ai documentation on EXAMPLE(") AND TEMPLATE (@) MODES:
"Each ‘User says’ expression can be in one of two modes: Example Mode (indicated by the “ icon) or Template Mode (indicated by the @ icon).

Examples are written in natural language and annotated so that parameter values can be extracted. You can read more on annotation below.
Templates contain direct references to entities instead of annotations, i.e., entity names are prefixed with the @ sign.

To toggle between modes, click on the “ or @ icon."